# Generating li tags using helper methods fails in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using rails 2.3.11

In my `views/layout/application.html.erb`

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <%= myhelper('t')%>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

I am calling `myhelper` method to generate `li` in `application_helper.rb`

```
def myhelper(v)
  if v
    content_tag(:li, link_to("3",/users_path))
  end
end
```

I have confirmed that `myhelper` gets called but it doesn't generate the `li` tag.

Please give suggestions.

**EDIT**

I am trying to generate li tag based on the value received from one of the helper method in the same application helper which is collections

```
 def myhelper(v)

       collections.each_with_index do |c,i|
       case c
           when 'c'
                     content_tag(:li, link_to("3", users_path))
           end
       end
end

def collections
  @enabled ||= Setting.get_enabled
end
```

where collections is an array received from one other helper method in the same helper -application helper

when i comment the two below lines

```
      collections.each_with_index do |c,i|

      end
```

li is generating .

why this helper method is not getting.Please give suggestions

Comment: Aruna, please specify your intent for this code and clean up your code. It is very hard to make sense of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Does `@enabled` contain expected values when used in `myhelper`? Is the value returned from `collections` as expected? What is the value of `v` -- is it true? Have you tried to run 
the code with breakpoints (i.e. in a debugger) or maybe used `puts` to try and figure out what the data is and whether the expected
code is being called at all? Please try all these things before editing the question again!

Comment: @Zabba - I tried all wat u said ..puts isworking insidewhen 'c' but tat time tag is not generating... if i comment the collections.each thing the tag is generating

Comment: What is the value and class name of "c" -did you check that?

Comment: @Zabba -- puts c.class returns string..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (no forward slash character appended before the named route users_path):

```
content_tag(:li, link_to("3", users_path))
```